# Error: "The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation"

Tags: php, install

Has anyone experience this error when running 'composer install' command via C-Panel Terminal?

"The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation"

[image: terminal error message]

Comment: See: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/28615/526

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proc\_open() has been disabled for security reasons](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28604/proc-open-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons)